# Display filename being processed by xlrd, python. No filename attribute of Book class

Tags: python, filenames, xlrd

I'm trying to do something that I feel should be very straight forward, but doesn't seem to exist as an attribute to the xlrd Book Class.

While parsing all of the xlsx files in a directory, I want to log which errors exist in which file.  In order to do this, I need to print the filename being processed.

GOAL:  Print name of file being processed by xlrd.  ie: "filename.xlsx" in example below

Example code:

```
Wb = xlrd.open_workbook ( "./data/excel_files/filename.xlsx" )
print "File being processed is: %s" % Wb.name_obj_list[0].name
```

This outputs "_xlnm._FilterDatabase".  I want to print "filename.xlsx".  The documentation of the Book Class doesn't have a simple way to do this.  http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.Book-class

Any advice?

Comment: There is nothing in the workbook object itself that indicates which file it resides in.  You can see this for yourself by taking any Excel file and making a copy of it with a different name.  The two files are byte-for-byte identical, yet have different names.  So even if, somehow, the original workbook stored the name of its file in there somewhere, then the copy would have the *wrong name* stored inside itself.  Also, the `open_workbook` method can accept input in the form of raw file contents (as a bytestring), in which case there would be no name, period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the simple approach:

```
for filename in glob('*.xls*'):
    try:
       wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
    except xlrd.XLRDERROR:
       print 'Problem processing {}'.format(filename)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the object Wb is passed into the excel parsing file.  I guess I could just pass the filename too, but thought there might be a way of extracting it from the Wb object.

Answer (score 0):

I just passed the filename with the Wb object from another class and printed it.